# please tell me how can i use the below mentioned elements using pdfmake

Tags: pdfmake

the below elements how can i use in the pdf make for create cricle, rectangle or any other shape

```
 'tableCellPadding'
 'cellBorder',
 'headerCellBorder',
 'oddRowCellBorder',
 'evenRowCellBorder',
 'tableBorder'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cmd').click(function () {
                  var docDefinition = { 

        pageMargins: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        content: [
                 canvas: [
                {
                    style: 'rectangleData',
                    type: 'rect',
                    x: 198,
                    y: -186,
                    w: 198,
                    h: 188,
                    r: 8,
                    lineWidth: 4,
                    lineColor: '#276fb8',

                },

                 ]
             }
           ]
       }
```